# How to launch the store for review?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

In windows phone 8, we could use `MarketPlaceReviewTask` to let user review our app. In Windows 8, seems this is the right way:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=MY_PACKAGE_FAMILY_NAME"));
```

But how to do that in Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone Runtime? what is the uri format? thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the replacement for MarketplaceReviewTask in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976718/whats-the-replacement-for-marketplacereviewtask-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal)

Answer (score 8):

It is almost the same except you need to add your app id dynamically. here is how.  It will work after you publish your app on the store(weather it is beta or production)

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=" + CurrentApp.AppId));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: new Uri("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=" + Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId)